# How to configure OMP_THREAD_LIMIT in tesseract directly in python code to disabling multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, environment-variables, tesseract

I'm using tesseract in a project that runs with docker-compose. I don't know how to configure a single processor core directly in my python file. I want to do this because there is slowness and over-consumption when you parallel Tesseract.

I found many similar topics but they only deal with how to configure OMP_THREAD_LIMIT on the command line.
Here is how tesseract is configured in my python code :

```
__tesseract_config_without_dir = "--psm 3 --oem 1 --dpi 300"

TESSERACT_DATA = os.environ.get(
    "TESSDATA_PREFIX", "/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/"
)

__tesseract_config = (
    __tesseract_config_without_dir
    + ' --tessdata-dir "{}"'.format(config.TESSERACT_DATA)
)
```

So I would like to add an option like 'OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1' in my __tesseract_config but I don't know how to write it.
In the tesseract documentation, we only find this informations :

"ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

OMP_THREAD_LIMIT

If the tesseract executable was built with multithreading support, it will normally use four CPU cores for the OCR process. While this can be faster for a single image, it gives bad performance if the host computer provides less than four CPU cores or if OCR is made for many images. Only a single CPU core is used with OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1."

Answer (score 6):

To disable multithreads for Tesseract I just added at the beginning of my code

```
os.environ['OMP_THREAD_LIMIT'] = '1'
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply.
I tried but I feel like nothing's change. 
I have a lot of python files in my project so I don't know if I must put it in the file where there is parallelism or in the configuration file or in another one.

Comment: I think you should add this in the file where you instantiate Tesseract

Comment: Does the python environment get pushed into the process that is running Tesseract? I don't know for sure but without the variable being EXPORTed, but instinct says this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Write a bash script that starts your python program. In that script, before your program is started run the following command:

```sh
export OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1
```